# Creating a dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox, desire2learn

The Valence API doesn't appear to have a mechanism for creating dropbox folders. Am I missing something?

I've looked through the documentation on docs.valence.desire2learn.com, and can't find a call for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct; currently the Valence APIs do not provide you with a way to create dropbox folders. At the moment, course creators/managers must create the dropbox folders through the Web UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create dropboxes using the  BCC (Bulk Course Create) utility, which is what my institution is looking at. You need to use a zip file containing the XML files which have the dropbox parameters, and reference these in the BCC csv file. You can create the zip files by doing an export from a D2L offering, or look at scripting the creation of these.

Comment: John is correct there. It would be reasonable to assume that D2L has it on the roadmap to fill out the Learning Framework APIs so that utilities like BCC can be re-factored to layer on top of the APIs entirely. There is movement in this direction, but not yet firm release commitments as to when this area in particular (dropbox creation) will get filled out.